# Angular 5 Reactive Forms - Radio Button Group

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I have 2 radio buttons, I'm using reactive forms and I have added the form controls within my component. The issue I am facing is that the name attribute has to be the same as the formControlName. When I set the name attribute as the same, I can only select 1 radio button -- can never unselect and select the other one. Only allows me to select the same one.

```
this.genderControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
```

and then added to my Form Group

```
genderControl: this.genderControl,
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="radio-inline">
  <input id="gender" type="radio" name="genderControl" formControlName="genderControl" />
  <label class="radio-label"> Male</label>
  <input id="gender" type="radio" name="genderControl" formControlName="genderControl" />
  <label class="radio-label">Female</label>
</div>
```

Form Group

```
    this.personalInfo = new FormGroup({
  searchControl: this.searchControl,
  titleControl: this.titleControl,
  firstNameControl: this.firstNameControl,
  middleNameControl: this.middleNameControl,
  lastNameControl: this.lastNameControl,
  birthdayControl: this.birthdayControl,
  genderControl: this.genderControl,
  phoneControl: this.phoneControl,
  taxCanadaControl: this.taxCanadaControl,
  provinceControl: this.provinceControl,
  countryControl: this.countryControl,
  taxCountryControl: this.taxCountryControl,

  creditControl: this.creditControl
});
```

Comment: Can you post how did you instantiate your `form` by FormBuilder and also your html file ?

Comment: Updated, I used FormGroup

Comment: Do you really need name attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio button in formArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852522/radio-button-in-formarray)

Comment: Just leave out the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I tried your code, you didn't assign/bind a value to your formControlName.

In HTML file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <label>
     <input type="radio" value="Male" formControlName="gender">
       <span>male</span>
   </label>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" value="Female" formControlName="gender">
       <span>female</span>
   </label>
</form>
```

In the TS file:

```
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.form = fb.group({
      gender: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Make sure you use Reactive form properly: `[formGroup]="form"` and you don't need the name attribute.

In my sample. words `male` and `female` in span tags are the values display along the radio button and `Male` and `Female` values are bind to `formControlName`

See the screenshot:
[image]

To make it shorter:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="radio" value='Male' formControlName="gender" >Male
  <input type="radio" value='Female' formControlName="gender">Female
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Hitting this also did you get a solution ?

Comment: I recommend still including the name attribute on the radio buttons, even though Angular doesn't need them.This is because radio buttons behave differently in the browser depending on whether they have a name to group them. Specifically, the behavior when tabbing into and out of radio groups is affected. This also prevents weird side-effects when you have multiple radio groups.

Comment: for me it did not work without name attribute of the radio buttons

Comment: how can I mark the default active for the first one `[checked]='true'` not seems working to me. Do I need to define some form control for it ? any idea how can I do that

Comment: @Santosh
```...gender: ['Male', Validators.required]
```
should mark Male as default, i.e checked

Comment: Can you post whole working code somewhere?

Answer (score 24):

IF you want to derive usg Boolean true False need to add "[]" around value

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="radio" [value]="true" formControlName="gender">Male
  <input type="radio" [value]="false" formControlName="gender">Female
</form>
```

Comment: double quotes around the `true` and `false` values: `[value]="true"`

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 16:

In HTML file:

```
<form action="POST" [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="processRegister()">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="">Gender</label>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" formControlName="gender">
      <label for="male">male</label>
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" formControlName="gender">
      <label for="female">female</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" >
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

In Ts file:

```
export class RegisterComponent {
  registerForm = this.builder.group({
    gender: this.builder.control('male')
  })

  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrService, private service: AuthService, private router: Router){

  }

  processRegister() {
    console.log("value form register: ", this.registerForm.value)
    if(this.registerForm.valid) {
      this.service.processRegiter(this.registerForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.toastr.success("Please contact admin for enable access", "Register success")
        this.router.navigate(["login"])
      })
    }else{
      this.toastr.warning('Please enter valid data');
    }
  }
}
```