# Radio Buttons in ngForm Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two radio buttons on my HTML page for gender selection (M or F).
How to retrieve which button was clicked in my typescript file? Here's the code

```html
<form>
  <label> Gender </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" required name='gender' value='Male' [(ngModel)]='gender'>Male
  <br>
  <input type="radio" required name='gender' value='Female' [(ngModel)]='gender'>Female
  <br>

  <button id="signup" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

On clicking the button, I want to assign M or F to a string in my typescript file.

Comment: The question has an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49078441/12376898

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Reactive Forms - Radio Button Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078286/angular-5-reactive-forms-radio-button-group)

Comment: do you want to trigger an event upon change, or to retrieve the value when submitting?

Comment: @RafiHenig just retrieve the value on submitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct. No need to change anything.

This is your template code.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <input type="radio"  required name='gender' value='Male' [(ngModel)]='gender'>Male
    <input type="radio" required name='gender' value='Female' [(ngModel)]='gender'>Female
     <button id="signup" type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

In your .ts file,

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

     gender: string = "Male";

     onSubmit() {
           console.log(gender); 
     }
}
```

This will give you the selected gender value.
Because you have used two way binding. It updates the ngModel whenever the input changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve which button click by add ngModelChange method

```
<label> Gender </label>
<br>
<input type="radio"  required name='gender' value='Male' [(ngModel)]='gender' (ngModelChange)="youMethodName(gender)">Male
<br>
<input type="radio" required name='gender' value='Female' [(ngModel)]='gender' (ngModelChange)="youMethodName(gender)">Female
<br>
   </div>
            <button id="signup" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Signup</button> </form>
```

in your ts file

```
youMethodName(model) {
   console.log("TCL: youMethodName -> model", model)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although, answer is already accepted. I want to give solution of this problem **if you do not want to use Two way data binding**. this way is useful for breaking down two way data binding. So, there is no need **for [(ngModel)]** .  Complete Working Demo found here in [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sojntt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

- Your HTML ...

  ```
  <form>
      <fieldset id="group1">
           <input type="radio" (change)="handleChange($event)" name="group1" value="Male"/>Male
           <input type="radio" (change)="handleChange($event)" name="group1" value ="Female"/> Female 
      </fieldset>

      <div *ngIf="_prevSelected"> {{ _prevSelected}} </div>

      <button (click)="click()">Show</button>
      <div *ngIf="clicked"> <span> selected value is {{_prevSelected}} </span></div>
  </form>
  ```
- Your class file is..

  ```
   private _prevSelected: any;
   clicked:boolean;

   handleChange(evt) {
     let target = evt.target;

     if (target.checked) this._prevSelected = target.value;
  }
  click(){
     this.clicked =true;
  }
  ```