# How to select any one radio button in a table row and this should be for all other rows as well. How to do this in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to select any one radio button in a table row and this should be for all other rows as well. I want the data to be as in the below image.
[image]

After using formControlName, the not working as above image.

**HTML Code**

```
 <form [formGroup]="feedbackForm" (ngSubmit)="submitData()">
            <table class="res-tbl">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="skill-tr" *ngFor='let skill of skills; let i = index;'>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="i==i">
                            <td class="table-data res-td" class="skill-td">
                                <b>{{skill.skillName}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{i}}" value="radio{{i}}"> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{i}}" value="radio{{i}}"> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{i}}" value="radio{{i}}"> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{i}}" value="radio{{i}}"> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{i}}" value="radio{{i}}"> 
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**TS Code**
I have no idea on how to use this in TS file. I tried using like below but not working as I expected.

```
   this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
          radio0:[''],
          radio1:[''],
          radio2:[''],
          radio3:[''],
          radio4:['']
        });
```

Comment: Give the radio buttons, which you want to group, the same `name` property, as it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Comment: I want to use formControlName not name @Geshode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Reactive Forms - Radio Button Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078286/angular-5-reactive-forms-radio-button-group)

Comment: No, this did not answer @Geshode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. You set the `value` to `radio[INDEX]`, too. So **all** radio buttons has the **same** value like *radio0*. So all will be selected if you click one. Change the `value` like 1, 2, 3... or custom property inside your skills like

```
skills = [ { skillName: "First", skillValueOne: 1, skillValueTwo: 2 .....} ]
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6numkr) is here to play.

**Solution with fixed indexes for values**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
<form [formGroup]="feedbackForm" (ngSubmit)="submitData()">
  <table class="res-tbl">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="skill-tr" *ngFor="let skill of skills; let i = index">
        <ng-container *ngIf="i == i">
          <td class="table-data res-td" class="skill-td">
            <b>{{ skill.skillName }}</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{ i }}" [value]="1" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{ i }}" [value]="2" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{ i }}" [value]="3" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{ i }}" [value]="4" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="radio{{ i }}" [value]="5" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: this is not working. All the buttons are selecting.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6numkr Here is the code to Stackblitz. It works as well. Only one RadioButton can be checked. I edited my answer with a preview.

Comment: I need to have multiple rows not just single row @Flo

Comment: skills = [{ skillName: 'First' }, { skillName: 'Second' }, { skillName: 'Third' }];
So simple add new skills! I have updated the Stackblitz, give it a try again.